# Why can I run create on model with undefined polymorphic association in seeds.rb but not in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I run the following code in my `seeds.rb`file.

```
page = BlocksEditor::Page.create(name: "A Page")
```

When I try to run the same code in a controller. I get a validation error saying that the polymorphic association is empty, which is true. I logged out `page` while running the seed and the type and id fields are empty as expected. `page.valid?` returns true.

Why doesn't the validation fail in the seed file? Better yet, how can I define a polymorphic association that is optional? I know I want the fields, but I know they sometimes won't be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Rails 5 [makes the belongs_to association mandatory](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html). Use `optional: true` to make it optional. I still don't know why the seed file gives different behavior than the controller, but this solves the problem.